# Mocking ASPNET MVC DependencyResolver with Rhino mock

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

While writing a unit test for one of the business logic(method), not able to mock ASP NET MVC `DependencyResolver` due to that getting null for this. Below is the line of code

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ITestDetails)) as ITestDetails;
```

Somehow wanted to mock this line.

Comment: Mock the resolver and set current to the mock. Where is is shown code being used. Show the test that is failing as well. That should help clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mock the resolver and its expected behavior

```
//create the new resolver that will be used to replace the current one
IDependencyResolver resolver = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDependencyResolver>();
//mock expected behavior
var testdetails = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITestDetails>();
resolver.Stub(_ => _.GetService(typeof(ITestDetails))).Returns(testDetails);
```

and set current to the mock.

```
//assign the mocked resolver.
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
```

So now when

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ITestDetails))
```

is invoked, it will provide the mocked resolver and behave as expected when unit testing